# Getting XSD content using PHP

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, xsd

I need to extract the content of an XSD file using PHP. **I don't want to validate it against an XML**; I just need to take some nodes and check some attributes.

Here is my XSD example:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml" schemaLocation="somelocation.xsd" /> 
  <xsd:complexType name="nameType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
       <xsd:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
         <xsd:sequence>
             <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="x" nillable="true" type="xsd:int" /> 
             <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="y" nillable="true" type="xsd:int" /> 
             <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="z" nillable="true" type="xsd:decimal" /> 
         </xsd:sequence>
       </xsd:extension>
  </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:element name="lz_anual_250" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature" type="layerType" /> 
</xsd:schema>
```

I don't know if this is possible, so I'm just asking to an expert on StackOverflow.

Thanks!

PS: I'm using CodeIgniter, so if anyone know any extension or similar to do this, post here please.

EDIT: Problem solved!

Here is a link that could help someone with the same problem as me:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php#57911

Simply, someone used DOMXPath class to navigate through the XSD read before using DOMDocument class (like rik told me). The XSD wasn't empty. I was trying to print_r, var_dump and echo the nodes but, obviously there wasn't contain info like a classical XML.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

XSD is XML itself. You can work with it like with any XML file.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('your.xsd');
// do whatever you want
```

Comment: Thanks rik. I'm checking this, but my XSD is not a file; it's a resource loaded from an extern URL (using HttpRequest).

Comment: That's what `DOMDocument::loadXML($source)` is for. ;-)

Comment: Oops, true. Sorry, I'm a little newbie with this. Using this function, PHP generates a warning and my $doc is empty. But when I open the same URL on IE, I can see the whole XSD. What do you think about this? Any suggestions? Thanks again rik :) EDIT: using 'load' instead of 'loadXML' solves my problem.

Comment: Sorry, but using 'load' instead of 'loadXML' works, but my $doc variable still empty.

Comment: This is the warning: "DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Start tag expected, '<' not found in Entity, line: 1". I really appreciate your help rik :) Using 'save' the XSD is saved successfully, but when I want to read it I only have a couple of nodes (not the entire XSD file).

Comment: The warning is due to the missing XML prolog. Dont care. Update the question, show how you try to read and tell what's missing.

Comment: Thanks again rik, I solved my problem. I edited my post to add the solution.